# Members vs subclasses in OOP

Tags: c++, oop

I've decided to try to remember what I learned in my object-oriented programming class a couple of years ago by writing a text based RPG game. I'm not sure I'm hoping to ever finish the job, and I don't care too much. I just want to re-learn how to write programs.

After remembering the basics of how functions, data-types and classes work in C++, I wrote the following code.

```
class Character
{
      string Name;

public:
       Character()
       {
           Name = "Charname";
       }

       string GetName(){return Name;}
       void SetName(string sName){Name=sName;}
};
```

Now I would like my characters to have races. The first idea was to create subclasses of the class Character, one for each of the allowed races. This seems to me like the thing to do in object-oriented programming. But I started thinking how it would work. I would like to be able to say things like "if Tom is a human, Clara is an orc, and Tom and Clara attempt to marry, give an error message." I would probably also like humans and orcs to have different methods for doing different things.

It seems to me that, broadly, in the former, I want to treat Race as if it were a *member* (which I understand as an attribute) of Character, and in the former, as if it were a *subclass*.

Is the former even possible to do if Human is a subclass of Character? That is, can an object know what class it's in?

And what should I do I and why?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function Virtual functions in combination with subclassing are probably what you're looking for. You can use a method called `getRace()` or something similar and define it appropriately for each class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design problem is called "specialization". In this case you want Race to be an attribute, not a subclass, because the behavior of all races is fundamentally the same. In cases where races confer a special ability handle that in a unified way across all races. For example, imagine only some races can see in the dark, this is how you do it:

```
int getVisionRange( int iCurrentLightLevel ){
    if( iCurrentLightLevel < LightLevel.DIM ){
       if( this.race == ORC || this.race == ELF ){
           return VisionRange.GOOD;
       } else {
           return VisionRange.NONE;
       }
    } else {
       return MAX_VISION_RANGE;
    }
}
```

or something along those lines.

Comment: Thank you. Could you refer me to some text that explains this problem in some detail? I've just googled it, and I see some explanations, but they're usually short. Is there an accessible overview with examples? It seems to me that there must be a grey area here somewhere, and it would be great if I could read about it.

Comment: Thinking in C++ by Bruce Eckel is kind of the standard book and he explains things very clearly. Good for absolute beginners and more experienced programmers too. Also, Design Patterns by Gamma is a classic. "Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby" by Metz is new book that is very very good on the "philosophy" of OO design. (Once you are done with these books, here's a tip for you: dump OO programming, its a waste of time. In the long run, using your own logic will serve you better. Paradigms like OO are just a distraction. Solve each problem de novo and in the end it will pay off.)

Comment: @TylerDurden By "dump" do you mean to 'completely ignore', or do you mean 'not blindly adhere to'? If you mean the latter, then definitely (OO is just a tool, and like any tool at times it's simply not useful). On the other hand, if you mean the former, then without some strong supporting reasoning that's a very, very bold statement.